# Why is this AutoLayout not updating the way one would expect?

Tags: autolayout, ios-autolayout

This has me stumped.  I have a view with two child labels as shown here...

[image]

Here are the constraints for the entire view:

[image]

All of those constraints have a weight of 1000.

The problem is the orange label has it's horizontal ContentHugging set to 1000 whereas the blue label has its horizontal ContentHugging set to 250, which, AFAIT means the orange label should hug its content causing the blue label to expand to fill the area thanks to the constraint between them with a length of zero.  Yet I'm seeing the exact opposite.  What gives?

Settings for the orange label

[image]

Settings for the blue label

[image]

So what the heck am I missing?!

### Update

After further research, this seems to be either a corrupted NIB file, or an issue with Interface Builder itself.  I say this because I created a second NIB with the exact same settings as above, but this time it worked as expected. (I even copied the views themselves from one to the other.)

To be sure, I went through everything view-by-view and compared all values and constraints and it all looked completely identical.

While I could open up the nib itself and compare the raw text to see if there was something odd, since the new one works, I'm considering this as an anomaly, meaning unless someone can point out a mistake made above that I'm still not seeing, I will close this out as such.

Comment: did you try to set both label's content compression resistance to same value?

Comment: Unless you are accidentally looking at the settings for the wrong labels, what you have *should* do what you expect. When I set up a cell with setting to match what you've shown, the Orange label does in fact "shrink" to fit its text, with the blue label stretching to fill the width. I'd suggest deleting the cell prototype and start with a fresh one. Maybe something in IB is quirked?

Comment: As a side note... unless you have specific reasons to change the other Hugging and Compression values, I'd leave them at the defaults. Can't provide hard-evidence related to it, but it *seems* more reliable.

Comment: I definitely have reasons to change them from their defaults because there are future constraints (not yet added) where all of this comes into play.  And I'm also definitely not looking at the wrong items. Checked it a bunch of times.  Ironically, when I recreated the exact same thing in a different nib, it worked, making me believe this is a case of a corrupted nib, not something wrong with the autolayout settings.  Since you too agree the above *should* work, if others also agree, I'll close this as an anomaly and not a problem with the design.